# how can i find or send shortest path to drawing route google distance matrix api?

Tags: google-maps, shortest-path, google-distancematrix-api

I want to draw a route without traffic calculation. I try distance matrix service but ı can't find solution so when the response back from distance matrix service ı want to compare the routes and send shortest path to drawing but ı failed that too...  Can you guys help or suggest anything?

```
 directionsService
            .route({
                origin: document.getElementById("start").value,
                destination: document.getElementById("end").value,
                travelMode: "DRIVING",
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,

                drivingOptions: {
                    departureTime: new Date(Date.now()),
                    trafficModel: 'pessimistic'
                }
            })

            .then((response) => {

                directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);

                console.log(response);

                for (var i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++) {
                    shortest.push(response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value);
                }
                console.log(shortest);

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to draw a route without traffic calculation.

As far as I can tell, this is not possible. It looks like you already found the [traffic_model](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#traffic_model) parameter for modifying traffic assumptions.

Comment: İs there any other way without this code? any possible algorithm for calculating distance ? or is there any other technique for not including traffic at all?